# Interrupting a thread while it is running; what is the impact of the next interruption?

Tags: java, multithreading, interruption

Let's assume thread t1 is running (i.e. not in a sleep, wait or join state). Another thread t2 interrupts t1. The Javadoc says t1's interrupted status will be set.

Let's assume t1 falls into sleep, wait or join status later. What happens?

i) Is thread t1 automatically raised with an `InterruptedException` since it had an interrupted status?

Let's assume t1 is still into a sleep, wait or join state. Let's imagine t2 interrupts t1 again:

ii) Is thread t1 raised with an `InterruptedExecution` or does it need to clear its interruption status with a call to `interrupted()` first?

Is there an official Java position on this one?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case ("i"), yes, the sleeping thread will get popped out of its call to `Thread#sleep()` by way of an `InterruptedException` being thrown. At this point, the thread's status flag represented by [`Thread#isInterrupted()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29) will be cleared; calling `Thread#isInterrupted()` would return false. Since the `InterruptedException` is in flight, the message has been sent to all transitive callers.

It's then the callers' responsibility to catch that exception and do one of two things:

- either exit the current thread, or
- call [`Thread#interrupt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) on the current thread (that is, `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`)

When you say that thread "t1" is "still in a sleep, wait, or join state," the only way it could be so after its initial call to `Thread#sleep()` exited via `InterruptedException` is if it caught the exception, ignored it, and called on some blocking method like `Thread.sleep()` again before thread "t2" has a chance to interrupt it a second time.

If thread "t2" were to interrupt thread "t1" again *while "t1" is currently blocked on an interruptible method call*, "t1"'s call will again exit with an `InterruptedException`. Otherwise, the thread's interruption flag will be set for later detection.

Every time one calls `Thread#interrupt()`, the the *interruption status* of that target thread will be set to "true," meaning the thread has been interrupted since its *interruption status* was last cleared. The next time that the interrupted thread attempts to make a blocking call to an interruptible method, the thread's *interruption status* will be cleared and the method will throw `InterruptedException`.

Note that clearing the *interruption status* like that does not lose information so long as the clearing is immediately followed by throwing `InterruptedException`. A thrown `InterruptedException` is best interpreted as, "This thread had its *interruption status* set at some point prior, and now it's your responsibility to react and, usually, to warn subsequent callers of the intended interruption." You achieve the latter objective by calling `Thread#interrupt()` after catching `InterruptedException`, restoring the *interruption status* for others to see.

See the book [*Java Concurrency in Practice*](http://jcip.net/) for a more authoritative description of this protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the interrupted state of a thread clears the state flag; that is to say, the code that raises an `InterruptedException` is clearing the state, as your own code that manually samples the state.